# How to draw a fixed bitmap on a View class

Tags: android, class, view, bitmap, fixed

I'm blocked from some hours in a basic problem. I just want to know how can I draw in a View class something simple like a bitmap on a rectangle (the rect will occupy 70% of the screen) and make this draw stay fixed on the background all the time without the need to invalidate it every cycle of the onDraw method (no reason to invalidate it because no change happen to it). That is the question, many thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to draw something wirhout .... drawing it?

Comment: I just want to draw it without ... RE-drawing it

Comment: if a View is invalidated then onDraw is called and you need to redraw the content, so you cannot avoid that